# Не парсится json при попытке отправить запрос post, put. Rspec, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Пытаюсь отправить запрос методом `put` и `post`. Не парсит params, однако на методе `#get` все в порядке.

**user_spec.b**:

```
put '/api/v1/users/:id' do

  let!(:id) { user_second.id }

  parameter :email, "Email of user, have to be unique, cannot be blank", required: true, :scope => :user

  let!(:email) { 'test@test.test' } 

  example_request "Update a specific user(valid)" do
    #expect(status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

лог такой:

```
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # JSON::ParserError:
 #   795: unexpected token at 'user[email]=test%40test.test'
 #   /home/krava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'rspec_api_documentation'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: а код запроса-то к серверу покажите.

Comment: Может быть, ошибка в JSON

Comment: По всей видимости, это вопрос больше об `rspec_api_documentation`, там есть DSL для описания запросов. Я этой конкретной штукой не пользовался, но рагадка где-то там.